# Create a Django model instance concurrent with the creation of another Django model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating a simple record keeping app in Django 1.11 that keeps track of what happens in games turn by turn. What I'd like to do is when I create an instince of Game automatically create the first dependent Turn instance.

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(param)
    active = models.BooleanField(param)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        Turn(game=self, turn=1).save()

class Turn(models.Model):
    turn = models.IntergerField(param)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

please suggest a better method becuase I get ValueError on the save method.

Comment: turn object has not attribute game

Comment: thanks for the catch, I have to write my app on an offline network so i was bound to miss typing a key component here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.create` method  and `save()` function instead of `__init__` like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
    Turn.objects.create(turn=1, game=self)
```

More information [about save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)